# iCloud Key-Value-Store Synchronization issues (NSUbiquitousKeyValueStoreDidChangeExternallyNotification not called)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ios8, icloud

i am writing a small universal game for iOS. 
the highscore will be synched accross devices through an iCloud Key/Value store.

getting the newest score:

```
func retrieveHighestScore() -> Int64 {
        let iCloudScore: Int64 = NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore.defaultStore().longLongForKey(KeyValueKeyClassification.KeyHighscore.toRaw())
        let localScore: Int64 = Int64(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey(KeyValueKeyClassification.KeyHighscore.toRaw()))
        var result: Int64 = 0

        if localScore > iCloudScore {
            storeNewHighscore(localScore)
            result = localScore
        } else {
            storeNewHighscore(iCloudScore)
            result = iCloudScore
        }
        return result
    }
```

storing a new highscore

```
func storeNewHighscore(newScore: Int64) {
        NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore.defaultStore().setLongLong(newScore, forKey: KeyValueKeyClassification.KeyHighscore.toRaw())
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(Int(newScore), forKey: KeyValueKeyClassification.KeyHighscore.toRaw())
        if NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore.defaultStore().synchronize() {
            println("Synched Successfully")
        }
    }
```

for some reason however the scores are not synched.

- no errors
- no crashes
- no null values

i always get the highest score from the current device, never the one achieved on others.

could the reason be within itunesconnect or is something wrong with my code? i am using an ipad and an iphone for testing, both logged in to my own icloud account.

i am registering for the changes like this:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "icloudKeyValueChanged", name: NSUbiquitousKeyValueStoreDidChangeExternallyNotification, object: nil)
        if NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore.defaultStore().synchronize() {
            println("initial Synched Successfully")
        }

        return true
    }
```

but the function 'icloudKeyValueChanged' is never called.

iCloud Capabilities all are ok as it seems:

[image]

Comment: I believe iCloud storage requires plist-objects(?) You probably need to wrap some of those Ints in NSNumber...

Comment: @nickfalk im quite sure that's not the problem. otherwise something like 'setlonglong' wound not exist

Comment: OK, I had a very similar problem with `Swift` + `NSUserDefaults` where using Ints would not gel, apart from the fact that no errors were reported.

Comment: did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Logging of iCloud on my device, and logging back in, solved the problem :-)

Answer (score -1):

Its probably just simply adding the synchronize to your highscore storer:

```
func storeNewHighscore(newScore: Int64) {
    NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore.defaultStore().setLongLong(newScore, forKey: KeyValueKeyClassification.KeyHighscore.toRaw())
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(Int(newScore), forKey: KeyValueKeyClassification.KeyHighscore.toRaw())

    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()

    if NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore.defaultStore().synchronize() {
        println("Synched Successfully")
    }
}
```

Comment: no - you never need to synchronie nsuserdefaults. and the ubiquous (icloud) store is synchronized & the 'synched successfully' log is put out. it just does not arrive on other devices - has nothing to do with the local nsuserdefaults