# iCloud Key Value Storage Changes Not Called (NSUbiquitousKeyValueStoreDidChangeExternallyNotification)

Tags: ios, swift, icloud, key-value

`NSUbiquitousKeyValueStoreDidChangeExternallyNotification` Does not get called at all?

```
var keyStore: NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore?

viewDidLoad{

NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self,
            selector: "ubiquitousKeyValueStoreDidChange:",
            name: NSUbiquitousKeyValueStoreDidChangeExternallyNotification,
            object: keyStore)



userDefinedLabelOne.text = keyStore?.stringForKey("userDefinedStringOne") <---this is changed

 }





func ubiquitousKeyValueStoreDidChange(notification: NSNotification) {

     println("Changed")  <---- Not called


    }
```

Already checked here [iCloud Key-Value-Store Synchronization issues (NSUbiquitousKeyValueStoreDidChangeExternallyNotification not called)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26572855/icloud-key-value-store-synchronization-issues-nsubiquitouskeyvaluestoredidchang)

Key value storage selected in iCloud capabilities

CloudKit sharing data ok

The data is saved to the cloud but notifications of changes are not being called

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By signing out of iCloud accounts and back in all started working correctly

Comment: no dumb way. This actually worked. Wow apple, just wow. thanks bud

Answer (score 0):

Take a look. This code works for me:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    prepareKeyValueStoreObserver()

    return true
}

func syncKeyValueStore() {
    let kvStore: NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore = NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore.defaultStore();
    kvStore.synchronize()
}

func prepareKeyValueStoreObserver(){
    let kvStore: NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore = NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore.defaultStore();
    let notificationsCenter: NSNotificationCenter = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()
    notificationsCenter.addObserver(self, selector: "ubiquitousKeyValueStoreDidChange:", name: NSUbiquitousKeyValueStoreDidChangeExternallyNotification, object: kvStore)

    syncKeyValueStore()
}
```

Comment: I may not be implementing it correctly but that does not work for me

Comment: Edited: It is important to note that when your app starts you should call synchronize immediately so that your app knows to check the iCloud Key-Value Store for changes at launch.

Comment: Yes that has been done and confirmed as synced though logging